# How to run more executions of same @Scheduled jobs in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an implementation like this which doesn't work. As you see, job takes ~5sec and should run on `fixedRate` 1sec. That means there should be ~5jobs running in parallel but Spring wait to finish a job before starts another one...
If I add second @Scheduled job 'schedule2' with the same and parameters, I have 2 different jobs running in parallel but never the same job. Is it somehow possible to achieve this?

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
private void schedule1() {
    int index = atomicInteger1.addAndGet(1); 
    logger.info("Run Schedule1 nr.{} started at: {}", index, LocalDateTime.now());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        logger.info("Schedule1 nr.{} finished at: {}", index, LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
}
```

Comment: `That means there should be ~5jobs running in parallel but Spring wait to finish a job before starts another one.` it means those are not running in parallel.

Comment: Are you trying to do scheduling or parallel processing? It seems you want the latter, but you're abusing scheduling for it.

Comment: @Kayaman I am trying to schedule job to run every second(or minute or day or ...) even if previous run of same job didn't finish already

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, yes, and that's my problem which I want to solve...

Comment: @mirec I know *what*, but I'm asking about the *why*. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each scheduled task will **never** run in parallel in this case. That's because the task takes *longer* than the given `fixedRate`. Why? Because [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is called, and as the documentation says (bolded is mine):

> ... If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but **will not concurrently execute**.

One way of solving this is by using [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) and [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html). Many examples are available in the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#secheduling-enable-annotation-support):

```
@EnableAsync
public class Example {

  @Async
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
  public void schedule1() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Maroun, thank you for your answer. "Each scheduled task will never run in parallel **in this case**". Is there any case when it will run in parallel?

Comment: @mirec You should use `@Async` and `@EnableAsync`. Look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) for details.

Comment: yeah, that did the trick, thank you @Maroun.  I enabled async with `@EnableAsync` but I didn't annotated method itself with `@Async`  Will you, please, add your most recent comment to your original answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achieve what you want, you should manage the threads by your own, calling to a service from the job in a separate thread.. but I don't see a reason to do that at least you're only testing and playing with Jobs at home for pet projects.

Anyway, have a look at this:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-future

Comment: thank you @geeksusma. I just wonder why this I think legitimate expectation isn't managed by spring itself, somehow. Like another parameter... &amp;Scheduled(allowParallel = true) In fact, this should make real difference in between &amp;Scheduled with _fixedDelay_ vs _fixedRate_